# VB.NET Update User Control Immediately When UI Editor Changes

Tags: user-controls, editor

I have a User Control in VB.NET (VS 2010) inherited from a picturebox.  I also have a class that holds 40 or so properties for the control.  I also have a form with a property grid that is used as an editor.  The editor form opens when clicking the "Custom" property of the control in the IDE.  On the form are an OK and Cancel button which either saves or discards changes.

All of this works fine, but I need to have my control "refresh" when a property changes in the grid.  The property grid has an event for this, but I don't know how to call or invoke my sub in the control to essentially repaint the control.  If I call the sub directly nothing refreshes on the control until after I close the editor form (dialog).  Is there a way to have the control repaint/redraw with the editor dialog still open?

Thanks,
EluZioN

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Context.Instance` which is passed when your UI_Editor is invoked. In the `GetEditStyle` override, a `Context` object is passed. This holds a reference to the calling `UserControl`.

I do something like this (CUSTOM UI_TYPE_EDITOR):

```
Dim ContextOBJ as MyUserControl

Public Overrides Function GetEditStyle(ByVal context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext)......

contextOBJ = CType(context.Instance, MyUserControl)
```

In the `GetEditValue` override, you can call `ContextOBJ.Refresh` and your `UserControl` should immediately reflect any changes. It works for me.